# JavaScript start counting from timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have this counter that I want to start from a specific timestamp (1385132831.818785) instead of 0. How do I do that?

```
startTimer: function(el) {      

         var counter = 0, 
         cDisplay = $(el);
         var format = function(t) {

             var minutes = Math.floor(t/600),
                 seconds = Math.floor( (t/10) % 60);
             minutes = (minutes === 0) ? "" : (minutes === 1)? minutes.toString()     + ' min ' : minutes.toString() + ' mins ';
             seconds = (seconds === 0) ? "" : seconds.toString() + ' secs';
             cDisplay.html(minutes + seconds);
         };
        setInterval(function() {
           counter++;
           format(counter);
        },100);

    }
```

Comment: How about `var counter = 1385132831.818785, `

Comment: That returns 2308555 mins 10 secs

Comment: Your timestamp is almost 44 years old ; ).

Comment: what do you want to display

Comment: @Newcoma - does it really look like a valid timestamp ?

Comment: @adeneo it looks like in seconds... `1385132831000` gives `Nov 22 2013 20:37:11 GMT+0530`

Comment: if i test it in http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ I get 11 / 22 / 13 @ 3:07:11pm UTC. I want to show in hours minutes and seconds from that date/time to current time and then start counting.

Comment: @Newcoma - note where it says "seconds since...." on that site, and remember that javascript uses milliseconds, so as noted by Teemu, your timestamp is a bit outdated.

Comment: You are right : ) I can't get a another timestamp. So there is nothing I can do ?

Comment: @Newcoma see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L8eAW/

Comment: @Newcoma since you are interested only in seconds you can easily convert the javascript time in milliseconds to time in seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var el = '.timer';
var start = 1385132831,
    cDisplay = $(el);
var format = function (t) {
    var hours = Math.floor(t / 3600),
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60 % 60),
        seconds = Math.floor(t % 60),
        arr = [];
    if (hours > 0) {
        arr.push(hours == 1 ? '1 hr' : hours + 'hrs');
    }
    if (minutes > 0 || hours > 0) {
        arr.push(minutes > 1 ? minutes + ' mins' : minutes + ' min');
    }
    if (seconds > 0 || minutes > 0 || hours > 0) {
        arr.push(seconds > 1 ? seconds + ' secs' : seconds + ' sec');
    }
    cDisplay.html(arr.join(' '));
};
setInterval(function () {
    format(new Date().getTime() / 1000 - start);
}, 1000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L8eAW/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = {
            showTime: function (cDisplay, timestamp) {
                var now = new Date(),
                    time = new Date(now - Math.floor(timestamp * 1000));
                cDisplay.html(time.getUTCHours() + ' hours ' + time.getUTCMinutes() + ' mins ' + time.getUTCSeconds() + ' secs');
                setTimeout(function () {timer.showTime(cDisplay, timestamp);}, 1000);
            }
        };
    timer.showTime($('#el'), 1385132831.818785);
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQ786/2/).